# Strange behanvior on button-click event in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am encountering a very strange behavior shown by my program written in AngularJs. I am implementing infinite-scrolling in AngularJs. The below function gets called on a successful AJAX call, that takes place when:

1. The user scrolls to the end of screen.
2. The selects some filters, and hits the "Search" button.

In the first case, the data fetched from the AJAX call is appended to the existing list. In the second case, I intend to completely empty any existing data in the list, and display the new data. Here is my code to do that:

```
$scope.successCallBack=function(data){
    $('#spn-model-buffering-image').hide();   //hide the loading spinner icon
    if($scope.providersList === null) {
       $scope.providersList = []; /* init if null */
    }
    if($scope.scrolled === 'true'){
    /*If it was an scroll-end event, then simply append the new data to the existing one*/
    Array.prototype.push.apply($scope.providersList, JSON.parse(data.serviceproviderlist));   //push the new data to the existing list
    }
    else{
    /*If the user clicks on "Search Providers" button, then new data are fetched, and occupy the entire list view*/
    $scope.providersList=[];
    $scope.providersList=JSON.parse(data.serviceproviderlist);
    }

   $scope.serviceName = data.category;
   $scope.$apply();
   viewToBeDisplayed(LIST_VIEW);
   $scope.scrolled='true';
}
```

So, after a successful AJAX call, the above method is called. It hides the buffering image, and checks if the variable named **scrolled** is set to true. If yes, then it means that the event is not button-click, but the user has reached the end of screen, and hence, data have to be appended. Else, the user has clicked on the button, and hence, data have to be displayed fresh.

This is the function that gets called on button-click event:

```
$scope.getFilteredData=function(){
     $scope.scrolled='false';
     $scope.getMoreData();
}
```

**My problem**: Data keeps appending to the existing list all the time, except for when I click the button multiple times in quick succession. Then, the new data occupy the complete list view.

Can someone suggest me what I might be doing wrong? Thanks!

Here is the AJAX call code:

```
$scope.getMoreData=function(){
      $('#spn-model-buffering-image1').show();   //while the data are being fetched, display the loading spinner
      $scope.updateAjaxData();   //update AJAX data: pagekey, category, and reftag
      var url=$scope.getURL();
      A.ajax(url, {
          method: 'post',
          params: AJAX_DATA,
          success: function(data, s, x) {
              $scope.successCallBack(data);
          },
          error: function(xhr, statusText, errorThrown) {
              $scope.errorCallback(xhr);
          }
     });
  }
```

Comment: Where are you making the API call to fetch the new data?

Comment: I have added in to the question.

Comment: possibly problem is: when you do multiple clicks you move your screen and $scope.scrolled becomed false. then all data are replaced. Check this please. And in any case it is not a good idea to give user ability to send multipe requests by click. You can add isLoading flag and make a new call only when it is false.

Comment: Let me implement that. Will update you in a minute.

Comment: Does this helps?